# Scala: what if I used class instead of object for an Enumeration?

Tags: scala

Would anything bad happen if I wrote:

```
class TaskType extends Enumeration {
  type TaskType = Value
  val LINEAR_REGRESSION, POISSON_REGRESSION, LOGISTIC_REGRESSION, SMOOTHED_HINGE_LOSS_LINEAR_SVM, NONE = Value
};
```

The IDE and compiler seem fine with it. It gets me out of some `import TaskType._` which I have to insert if `TaskType` is an `object` rather than a `class`.

Comment: you can use some of the other alternatives to pure scala enumerations. there are a few. I grouped some solutions here: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/ and here http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums-part2/

Comment: Thanks @pedrorijo91 - That is very interesting and I like very much the way you have systematically evaluated the approaches. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It defeats the purpose of having an enumeration as a set of unique stable identifiers.

To use members of a class, we need an instance. The members of each instance will be different. In practical terms, `LINEAR_REGRESSION` instantiated in some part of the system will not be the same as a `LINEAR_REGRESSION` instantiated somewhere else.

eg.:

```
class TaskType extends Enumeration {
  type TaskType = Value
  val LINEAR_REGRESSION, POISSON_REGRESSION, LOGISTIC_REGRESSION, SMOOTHED_HINGE_LOSS_LINEAR_SVM, NONE = Value
}
val instance = new TaskType
val otherInstance = new TaskType


import instance._

val lr = LINEAR_REGRESSION

val lr2 = otherInstance.LINEAR_REGRESSION


lr == lr2
// false
```